# How to use this package "https://github.com/kazist/resellerclub-php-sdk" in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

While using the above package in `laravel` I'm getting error as

> "Class 'Kazist\ResellerClub\APIs\Controller' not found"

Please suggest me a solution how to call the reseller club api "url" in the controller.

```
 $request = file_get_contents('https://httpapi.com/api/domains/available.json?auth-userid=USER_ID&api-key=API_KEY&domain-name='.$slds.'&tlds='.$tlds.'');
```

Please help me with a solution how to `declare` the `domain-name` and tlds from the above url in `laravel`.

Answer (score 0):

For package installation:

From terminal go to your project's root directory and run this command:

```
composer require kazist/resellerclub-php-sdk
```

And then after successful installation one new folder called `kazist` will be created inside project's vendor directory.

For using api calls you need to use Guzzle http client https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle or use this [link](http://www.expertphp.in/article/laravel-php-guzzle-http-client-get-and-post-request-example).o

**Edit**

Yourcontroller.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use 

class Yourcontroller extends Controller
{

    $resellerClub = \Kazist\ResellerClub\ResellerClub(<userId>, <apiKey>, true); // Last argument is for testmode.

    // Get Available TLDs
    $resellerClub->domains()->getTLDs();

    // Check Domain Availablity
    $resellerClub->domains()->available(['google', 'example'], ['com', 'net']); // This will check google.com, google.net, example.com and example.net


}
```

Comment: I have installed the package already and I have a doubt in passing the domain-name and tld value in the url....Please help me with this

Comment: You can follow the usage details on github https://github.com/kazist/resellerclub-php-sdk#usage